# How to insert many variables into database with greatest ease and speed

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I am attempting to not create a duplicate question and have been searching for 2 days now without finding an answer that seems to apply to my situation, so I apologize in advance for asking a duplicate/dumb question if that is the case.

So I have a web form which the user uploads an excel file. this excel file needs to be placed into our mySQL database exactly as it is in the excel file. I have set up the database to match the same columns and headers. The issue is that this file has around 260 columns and each upload will contain about 100-500 records/rows. I am used to using the mysqli bind_param() but I am having difficulty finding a way to insert this as an array with 1 statement so that I do not have to write out close to 300 variables.  I have read that using PDO makes binding with an array easier but despite implementing more than 15 different examples, I cannot get any to work for various reasons. Below is the code I have right now. I am not very experienced with php but maybe someone can point me in the right direction. I am using PHPExcel to extract the file data and create a row array:

```
if(isset($_POST['source']) && $_POST['source'] > 0){
        $source = $_POST['source'];
        if($_FILES['myFile']['name']){
            $error = $_FILES['myFile']['error'];
            if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $inputFileName = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];
                include_once '../Assets/plugins/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

                $filetype = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
                $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($filetype);
                $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
                $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
                $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
                $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
                $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
                $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

                include_once('../Auth/masterClass.php');
```

NOTE: masterClass is simply a connection function (I have no issues with the connection)

```
$add = new master;
                    $con = $add->con();
                    switch ($source) {
                        case 1:
                            $headerData = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A1:'.$highestColumn.'1',NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
                            for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
                                $table_name = 'books';
                                $data = array();
                                $rowData = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
                                $result_set = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table_name` (".implode(', ',$headerData[0]).") VALUES (:".implode(', :',$rowData[0]).")");
                                function bindArrayValue($sql, $array){
                                    if(is_object($req) && ($req instanceof PDOStatement)){
                                        foreach($array as $key => $value){
                                            if(is_int($value)){
                                                $param = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                                            }elseif(is_bool($value)){
                                                $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                                            }elseif(is_null($value)){
                                                $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                                            }elseif(is_string($value)){
                                                $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                                            }else{
                                                $param = FALSE;
                                                if($param){
                                                    $req->bindValue(":$value",$value,$param);
                                                };
                                            };
                                        };
                                    };
                                }
                                bindArrayValue($result_set,$rowData);
                                $result_set->execute();
    //                          $sql = "INSERT INTO `books` (
    //                          `id`, `title`, `author`, `status`
    //                          ) VALUES (NULL,?,?,?)";
    //                          if($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)){
    //                              $stmt->bind_param("sss", $data[0], $data[1], $data[2]);
    //                              if($stmt->execute()){
    //                                  $success = 1;
    //                              } else {
    //                                  echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error: '.$sql."<br>".$con->error.'</div>';
    //                              }
    //                          }
                            }
                            if($success == 1){
                                echo '<div class="alert alert-success">File successfully saved to the database!</div>';
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Source match not found!</div>';
                    }
                    $con->close();
                }else{
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">File upload error!</div>';
                };
            }else{
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">ERROR: File cannot upload!</div>';
            };
        }else{
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">ERROR: File source not set!</div>';
        };
    ?>
```

This code is telling me I have a SQL syntax error. I can elaborate with whatever you all will need.

**EDIT:** Tried to "BIND ONCE" this is what I have, please advise:

```
case 1:
                        $table_name = 'books';
                        $headerData = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A1:'.$highestColumn.'1',NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
                        $result_set = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $table_name ".implode(', ',$headerData[0])."=:".implode(', ',$headerData[0]).")");
                        bindArrayValue($result_set,$rowData);
                        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
                            $rowData = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
                            function bindArrayValue($sql, $array){
                                if(is_object($req) && ($req instanceof PDOStatement)){
                                    foreach($array as $key => $value){
                                        if(is_int($value)){
                                            $param = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                                        }elseif(is_bool($value)){
                                            $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                                        }elseif(is_null($value)){
                                            $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                                        }elseif(is_string($value)){
                                            $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                                        }else{
                                            $param = FALSE;
                                            if($param){
                                                $req->bindValue(":$key",$value,$param);
                                            };
                                        };
                                    };
                                };
                            }
                            $result_set->execute();
                        }
```

Comment: You can not bind values e.g. :4. You must set names eg: :somename and then  `$req->bindValue(":somename",4,$param);`. Now you have `$req->bindValue(":4",4,$param);`. You can also instead of `:name` use `?`

Comment: You're doing all of that wrong. You prepare a statement **ONCE**, bind parameters **ONCE**, then re-use that prepared statement multiple times in a loop by re-assigning new values to the bound parameters each time. preparing/binding INSIDE the loop negates one of the primary purposes of preparing statements in the first place: paying the compiling/binding price once.

Comment: But you can use `:param4`

Comment: Thank you nospor ... I will adjust that. @Marc B when you are finished chastising my self declared lack of knowledge on this subject could you be helpful and provide a link to a solution or show me what I am doing wrong by providing an example as I am not sure how to do what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [**LOAD DATA INFILE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) for this.
To use you require to save Excel file as csv.

```
$sql ="LOAD DATA INFILE 'csvfile.csv' 
    INTO TABLE tablename 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;"
$db->exec($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER:** Okay so I figured this out with the pseudo direction of @Marc B and this handy link: http://thisinterestsme.com/pdo-prepared-multi-inserts/

here is my working code:

```
            include_once('../Auth/masterClass.php');
            $upload = new master;
            $pdoObject = $upload->conn();

            switch ($source) {
                case 1:
                    $tableName = 'books';
                    $data = array();
                    $headerData = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A1:'.$highestColumn.'1',NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
                    for ($rec = 2; $rec <= $highestRow; $rec++) {
                        $rowData = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A'.$rec.':'.$highestColumn.$rec,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
                        $comb_data = array_combine($headerData[0],$rowData[0]);
                        $data[] = $comb_data;
                    }
                    function pdoMultiInsert($tableName, $data, $pdoObject){
                            //Will contain SQL snippets.
                            $rowsSQL = array();
                            //Will contain the values that we need to bind.
                            $toBind = array();
                            //Get a list of column names to use in the SQL statement.
                            $columnNames = array_keys($data[0]);
                            //Loop through our $data array.
                            foreach($data as $arrayIndex => $row){
                                    $params = array();
                                    foreach($row as $columnName => $columnValue){
                                            $param = ":" . $columnName . $arrayIndex;
                                            $params[] = $param;
                                            $toBind[$param] = $columnValue; 
                                    }
                                    $rowsSQL[] = "(" . implode(", ", $params) . ")";
                            }
                            //Construct our SQL statement
                            $sql = "INSERT INTO `$tableName` (" . implode(", ", $columnNames) . ") VALUES " . implode(", ", $rowsSQL);
                            //Prepare our PDO statement.
                            $pdoStatement = $pdoObject->prepare($sql);
                            //Bind our values.
                            foreach($toBind as $param => $val){
                                    $pdoStatement->bindValue($param, $val);
                            }
                            //Execute our statement (i.e. insert the data).
                            return $pdoStatement->execute();
                    }
                    if(pdoMultiInsert($tableName, $data, $pdoObject)){
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-success">File successfully saved to the database!</div>';
                    }
                    break;
                default:
            }
```